# No module named 'mywebsite'

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that I downloaded from a Github repo where the main app is not called "mywebsite" (like instructed in the django tutorial).

Everytime I run `python manage.py runserver` i get the following error.

Conceptually I understand the error, but practically I don't. The issue can't be that I have always need to name my repo "mywebsite" right?

This is the current repo structure.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/Yggdrasil/yggdrasil/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/nicolamacchitella/Documents/GitHub/familytree/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywebsite'
```

Comment: Open the folder yggdrasil and find the file 'settings.py'. Open it and then search for some reference to 'mywebsite'

Comment: Hey, where have you used `mywebsite`? 

It looks like you want to use mywebsite instead of mainapp, in that case rename mainapp with mywesite and search every place where mainapp is used and replace with mywebsite. In VS Code, you can search mainapp and replace with mywebsite all at once.

Comment: I tried! I can't find any instance of `mywebsite` so I am quite confused. This is the repo I cloned https://github.com/KeithPetro/Yggdrasil

Comment: I have made some updates to the repo that will be very important to you, I did not face the `No module names 'mywebsite'`. However, the project is outdated, with that being said I made a PR here https://github.com/KeithPetro/Yggdrasil/pull/16

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because of your project name. You have 2 options at the moment: (1) rename back to mywebsite or (2) rename all occurences of "mywebsite" in your project to your project name.

If you so choose (2), check your project settings and you'll see lot of variables like this `ROOT_URLCONF = 'mywebsite.urls'` for which you have to change to `ROOT_URLCONF = 'yggdrasil.urls'`. And you must also do that in all your apps and everywhere else that uses `mywebsite` as root reference.

Comment: that's what I thought, but I don't see any "mywebsite" instance in the repo. I searched for it. It seems to be almost something in the compiled code.

Comment: Did you search everywhere, including manage.py?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the code in the repo and apparently everything seems to be in order.

Looking then again at the error OP gets, it starts in line

```
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

which then searches for a file using a path different than Windows, File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python.... This shows that OP is having a problem importing the settings module.

After some digging, found [this page in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/#configuring-the-settings-module) that states

> If this variable isn’t set, the default wsgi.py sets it to mysite.settings, where mysite is the name of your project. That’s how runserver discovers the default settings file by default.

To fix it, try enforcing the value for in your [wsgi.py file](https://github.com/KeithPetro/Yggdrasil/blob/dev/yggdrasil/yggdrasil/wsgi.py), like

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "yggdrasil.settings"
```